# IE11 strange input background color behaviour

Tags: css, internet-explorer

As you can see below Internet Explorer 11 is behaving very strange when displaying input elements. The input background color should be white but it is showing up transparent or gray and it even changes randomly when hover over these input elements!

I can't find the solution so far, the CSS looks right to me. Any suggestions?

[image: http://project.codestars.nl/download/cs/ie-strange-inputs.jpg]
**Solution:**
I changed the compass box-shadow line from:

```
@include box-shadow(1px 1px 3px mix($white, $theme-color-3, 40%) inset);
```

to:

```
@include box-shadow(rgba(white, 0.1) 0 0 25px, mix($white, $theme-color-3, 40%) 1px 1px 3px inset);
```

Comment: it is working fine on IE 11 for me.

Comment: Strange that you guys can't seem to reproduce this. Anyway, I found a solution.

Comment: @Floris what is your solution please? I have a similar problem to this and I'm sure it could help other people.

Comment: @AlexHolsgrove Not sure if you are using SASS code like me. But I had to change the format of the sass box-shadow function. See solution in the post itself.